# Сложение и умножение матриц в PyTorch

Tags: матрицы, pytorch

**Часть 1**

**IN:**

```
A = torch.tensor([1,2])

B = torch.tensor([[1,2],[2,4]])

print(A+B)
```

**OUT:**

```
tensor([[2, 4],
        [3, 6]])
```

**Вопрос:**

Почему Torch не ругается, хотя матрицы разных размеров?

---

**Часть 2**

**IN:**

```
A = torch.tensor([[2,2],[1,2],[2,4]])

B = torch.tensor([[-7,5],[2,-1]])

print(A*B)
```

**OUT:**

RuntimeError

**Вопрос:**

И почему я не могу перемножить матрицы A(3x2) и B(2x2)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что операции `+` и `*` выполняют поэлементное действие. В первом случае у вас одномерный вектор длины 2 прибавляется к каждому вектору длины 2 двумерного вектора размера (2, 2).

В втором случае у вас оба операнда двумерные, но имеют разные размеры, поэтому их невозможно поэлементно никак перемножить. Чтобы выполнить умножение матрицы по правилу "строка на столбец", делайте одним из способов:

```
AB = A.mm(B)

AB = torch.mm(A, B)

AB = torch.matmul(A, B)

AB = A @ B # Python 3.5+
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44527447/7485582

Comment: Спасибо! С умножением понял, а есть специальный оператор или функция для корректного сложения матриц? Т.е. в чтобы в первом случае он выдал ошибку.

Comment: Я в документации не нашёл такого метода, но, может, я плохо смотрел. Вы легко  можете написать свою функцию, которая будет делать проверку.